# command mvnw package -Pprod docker:build hangs on

Tags: jhipster, docker-build

I am using jhipster 4.2.0 to generate a microservice. I am following the official documentation found here https://jhipster.github.io/docker-compose/ to run the micorservice in docker container.
When i run the command "mvnw package -Pprod docker:build", i can see in the logs that it is working and then hangs on at the following line without any error message:

```
[INFO] [00:21:10] I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.15.0.exe up
to date
```

here is a snippet of the log:

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:yarn (yarn install) @ gateway-demo ---
[INFO] Running 'yarn install' in E:\development\sources\jhipster-demo
[INFO] yarn install v0.21.3
[INFO] [1/4] Resolving packages...
[INFO] success Already up-to-date.
[INFO] $ webdriver-manager update && yarn run webpack:build
[INFO] [00:21:06] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists E:\development\
alone-3.3.1.jar
[INFO] [00:21:06] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-
[INFO] [00:21:06] I/update - chromedriver: file exists E:\development\sources
[INFO] [00:21:06] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.29.zip
[INFO] [00:21:08] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.29.exe up to date
[INFO] [00:21:09] I/update - geckodriver: file exists E:\development\sources\
[INFO] [00:21:09] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.15.0.zip
[INFO] [00:21:10] I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.15.0.exe up to date
```

Has anyone encounter this problem before ?

Comment: Does running `node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js ` from your project root, then building your app allow it to finish?  This used to be part of the package.json postinstall step and might still be needed...

Comment: Any updates on your issue?

Comment: I didn't try again since then. I will try the tutorial again when i have time.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with jhipster 4.3.0 while generating the gateway, running comnode node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js> and re-execute  does not solve the problem.